# QtCreator does not open terminal for building

Tags: terminal, qt-creator

I was using qmake build system in my `QtCreator 4.1.0-beta1`, everything was fine. When I ran my project, a new terminal popped up.

When I switched to CMake build system, no new terminal window was created anymore. How can I force QtCreator to run the build in a new terminal window like it does with qmake?

Comment: Why should CMake "create" a terminal window? Do you mean that the *program* doesn't open a terminal window? How do you run CMake? What is the output of CMake? Is everything created successfully? Can you build your program? What editor or IDE are you using?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg 
1. I thought it is standard behaviour. 
2. Yes
3. See next message
4. Of course, yes
5. `QtCreator 4.1.0-beta1`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg `Running "/usr/bin/cmake /home/user/Desktop/programms/TestBot '-GCodeBlocks - Ninja' -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:STRING=/usr/bin/g++ -DQT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE:STRING=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake" in /home/user/Desktop/programms/build-TestBot-Desktop-Default.
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/user/Desktop/programms/build-TestBot-Desktop-Default`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg `09:59:44: Running steps for project TestBot...
09:59:44: Starting: "/usr/bin/cmake" --build . --target all
ninja: no work to do.
09:59:44: The process "/usr/bin/cmake" exited normally.
09:59:44: Elapsed time: 00:00.`

Comment: If CMake popped up a new terminal for me, I would be angry.

Comment: @doug65536 but I got used to it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Projects -> Build & Run -> Run -> Check "Run in terminal"
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Weird. It was checked. Still opened in Application Output. Had to uncheck, clean, run qmake, rebuild. Still opened in Application Output. Go back, check again, then clean, run qmake, rebuild. Volia, it opens in new terminal. Confirmed this "bug" with a new console application. Same issue.